# how to fix linux kernel bugs without upgrading kernel?

Tags: driver, hostapd

i am installing hostapd in CentOS6.7 with two methods:

1) via rpm command using hostapd-2.0-7.el6.x86_64.rpm

2) by compiling tar.gz file following [this](http://jasonmaur.com/hostapd-centos-6/) tutorial

in both cases after editing hostapd.conf in /etc/hostapd/ directory, when i run `'service hostapd start'` i get following error:

```
Starting hostapd: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.confConfiguration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Could not add multicast membership for scan events: -2 (No such file or directory)
Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
```

after searching google i found out that its a kernal bug (kernel2.6.32-573.el6x86_64 for CentOS6.7 final release) and to fix it i have to upgrade my kernel. my requirenment is, not to upgrade whole kernal rather just to modify only the error-related file so that other kernal files remain intact. is it enough to fix the problem if so than anyone who can guide me how to do that?

[EDIT]: i am working on a server with specific OS and Software versions in a company. i want to make my own small similar network(infrastructure) at home with one of my laptop acting as server that should have same OS and Software versions so that i can work on the issues at home as well. to create network my server laptop should act as an access point for which i am using 'hostapd' open source package(mostly used). but my OS kernel version has a bug for hostapd. if i upgrade my kernel then at least some packages will also get updated that may change the type of issues i will have at home and in my office.

thanks

Comment: uhm, why don't you wish to upgrade the kernel? You need to update your question with the reason WHY you can't upgrade the kernel. Did you make significant changes to it? if not, just run `yum -y update kernel`

Comment: please read the modified question again...

Comment: okay. Seeing what the issue is, this question would be better suited on https://superuser.com/ I think